# How to display two JS fcnctions in the result?

Tags: javascript

How do I display both results in the same time?

First one

```js
$('#output')
  .html('')
  .append('hhtp://www.breakingnews.com/feeds/rss/' +
    $('#user').val())
  .attr('href', 'http://www.breakingnews.com/feeds/rss/' +
    $('#user').val());
}
});
```

Second One

```js
$('#output')
  .html('')
  .append('https://www.theguardian.com/world/' + user +
    '/rss')
  .attr('href', 'https://www.theguardian.com/world/' + user + '/rss');
```

Comment: Just a pointer, you first function has an extra `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just avoid `.html('')` in the second code, since it resets the content of the DOM element.

Comment: As you would do in an HTML code. Start your second result with `<br>` for instance.

Comment: I thought <br> is only use on html, not JS

Comment: Here, you are modifying the DOM (aka the html) from JS code. You use JS code to change HTML. Therefore, the content you append in your elements (`$('#output')` is an DOM node, aka a HTML block) must be HTML syntax. The function `.append()` will do the magic for you.

Comment: I put <br> in front of the second result, but it is not working.

Comment: It should. Is your second code like this? `$('#output').append('<br>https://www.theguardian.com/world/')`

Comment: Thx, Aurélien. I double check again and miss ' . It is working. Really appreciated!!!! You save rest of my day!